# Setting environment variables based on services in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running a simple app based on an api and web interface in Kubernetes. However, I can't seem to get the api to talk to the web interface. In my local environment, I just define a variable API_URL in the web interface with eg. localhost:5001 and the web interface correctly connects to the api. As api and web are running in different pods I need to make them talk to each other via services in Kubernetes. So far, this is what I am doing, but without any luck.

I set-up a deployment for the API

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: gcr.io/myproject-22edwx23/api:latest
      ports:
      - containerPort: 5001
```

I attach a service to it:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    component: api
  ports:
    - port: 5001
      targetPort: 5001
```

and then create a web deployment that should connect to this api.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: gcr.io/myproject-22edwx23/web:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        env:
          - name: API_URL
            value: http://api-cluster-ip-service:5001
```

afterwards, I add a service for the web interface + ingress etc but that seems irrelevant for the issues. I am wondering if the setting of API_URL correctly picks up the host of the api via http://api-cluster-ip-service:5001?

Or can I not rely on Kubernetes getting the appropriate dns for the api and should the web app call the api via the public internet.

Comment: Aren't you missing the `containerPort: 5001` in the `api-deployment` spec ?

Comment: yes, I updated that in the questions (it was there in my code)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check *API_URL* variable value, simply run

```
kubectl exec -it web-deployment-pod env | grep API_URL
```

The kube-dns service listens for service and endpoint events from the Kubernetes API and updates its DNS records as needed. These events are triggered when you create, update or delete Kubernetes services and their associated pods.

kubelet sets each new pod's search option in **/etc/resolv.conf**

Still, if you want to http from one pod to another via cluster service it is recommended to refer service's ClusterIP as follows

```
api-cluster-ip-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

You should have service IP assigned to env variable within your web pod, so there's no need to re-invent it:

```
sukhoversha@sukhoversha:~/GCP$ kk exec -it web-deployment-675f8fcf69-xmqt8 env | grep -i service
API_CLUSTER_IP_SERVICE_PORT=tcp://10.31.253.149:5001
API_CLUSTER_IP_SERVICE_PORT_5001_TCP=tcp://10.31.253.149:5001
API_CLUSTER_IP_SERVICE_PORT_5001_TCP_PORT=5001
API_CLUSTER_IP_SERVICE_PORT_5001_TCP_ADDR=10.31.253.149
```

To read more about [DNS for Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#a-records).  A service defines [environment variables naming the host and port](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables).

Comment: thanks, this is quite insightful. As is, the value for API_URL is literally http://api-cluster-ip-service:5001 and the webapp obviously no longer. expands it. I have tried setting API_URL=API_CLUSTER_IP_SERVICE_PORT, but to no avail. I don't want to change API_URL in the web app as then it becomes dependent on how I call my Kubernetes service. So it is still not clear to me how to get API_URL=http://10.31.253.149:5001 as an env variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use environment variables you can do the following:

Example in Python:

```
import os
API_URL = os.environ['API_CLUSTER_IP_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST'] + ":" + os.environ['API_CLUSTER_IP_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT']
```

Notice that the environment variable is based on your service name. If you want to check all environment variables available in a Pod:

```
kubectl get pods #get {pod name}
kubectl exec -it {pod_name} printenv
```

P.S. Be careful that a Pod gets its environment variables during its creation and it will not be able to get it from services created after it.

Comment: thanks, but I know how to use env variables in python. I need to know how to set them in the kubernetes yml file such that environment variable picks up the IP from the service

Comment: You don't need to set them in kubernetes if you have a service. Kubernetes automatically creates and exposes the services hosts and ports in all pods. Read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables) the explanation. I would use the command I showed above to check all environment variables. If you created the service after the pod, delete the pod.